# Data center router/firewall recommendations

Tags: vpn, firewall, cisco, router, datacenter

I'm looking for help deciding on a new router for our data center equipment. Currently, we've got about 10 machines, each with their own firewall. I'd like to get them all behind a single router and also create a vpn tunnel to our main office.

Requirements:

- Gigabit Ethernet
- Firewall
- Cisco compatible point-to-point VPN

Traffic primarily consists of external HTTP requests, averaging ~10Mb/s, surging up to ~150Mb/s.

The router at the main office is a Cisco 2821.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco 2911 ISR G2 should be sufficient, speced forwarding capacity of about 180Mbit. You get three GE copper interfaces in the standard configuration. If you need a fibre uplink the 2921 has an SFP slot in the standard configuration
To get the IOS firewall and full crypto features you need 2911-SEC-K9 bundle.

Having a second router for redundancy might be a good idea too.